# Is it possible to return a single value from MemberOf Active Directory and insert into SQL table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a single value from the MemberOf column, Is it possible to parse that value and return only part of that string such as the value 0012?
This is the output from the memberof catagory.

```
CN=Active VMS Users,OU=VMS,DC=evilcorp,DC=net CN=JOJOE\, MOE- 0012,
OU=Site Groups,OU=VMS,DC=evilcorp,DC=net
```

This is my code below

```
$ADARRAY= Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Users" -Recursive | 
Get-ADUser -Filter "Mail -like '*'" -and "MemberOf -like '*'"| 
Get-ADUser -Properties ('Mail','MemberOf')

<# this was my first try #>
    # $CN = $CN -split '^CN=(.+?-,\),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1'

ForEach($OBJECT in $ADARRAY){ 

    $NAME = $OBJECT.Name 
    $USER = $OBJECT.SamAccountName
    $EMAIL = $OBJECT.Mail

<# this was my second try #>
    ForEach($OBJECT in $ADARRAY.Memberof){
          $CN = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'CN' = $CN}

        $CN.OBJECT = $CN.Split(',')[0]

    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO $TABLE VALUES ('$USER','$CN','$EMAIL', '$NAME');"
        $SQL.CommandText = $INSERT 

        $SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

    } 
  }
}

$SQLCON.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use RegEx to do this. 
Just search for the data you'd like, split and/or extract what you want.

> Windows PowerShell: Extracting Strings Using Regular Expressions

```
$input_path = ‘c:\ps\emails.txt’ $output_file =
‘c:\ps\extracted_addresses.txt’ $regex =
‘\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b’ select-string
-Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

> 'techtalk.gfi.com/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions'
>
> PowerShell - Get a SubString out of a String using RegEx
>
> The PowerShell way

```
("OU=MTL1,OU=CORP,DC=FX,DC=LAB" -split ",")[0].substring(3)
```

> Using RegEx

```
("OU=MTL1,OU=CORP,DC=FX,DC=LAB" -split ',*..=')[1]
```

> 'lazywinadmin.com/2013/10/powershell-get-substring-out-of-string.html'

See a full PoSH RegEx write up here:

> 'community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2'  Chapter 13. Text
>   and Regular Expressions 
>   'community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2/posts/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions'